# R Tidymodels: What objects to save for use in production after fitting a recipe-based workflow utilizing pre-processing?

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-recipes

After designing a [Tidymodels](https://www.tidymodels.org/) recipe-based workflow, which is tuned then fitted to some training data, **I'm not clear what objects (fitted "workflow", "recipe", ..etc) should be saved to disk for use in predicting new data in production**. I understand I can use `saveRDS()`/`readRDS()`, `write_rds()`/`read_rds()`, or other options to actually do the saving/loading of these objects, **but which ones**?

In a clean R environment I will have incoming new raw data which will need pre-processed using the "recipe" I used in training the model. I then want to make predictions based on that data after it has been pre-processed. If I intend to use the `prep()` and `bake()` functions to pre-process the new data as I did the training data, then I will minimally need the recipe and original training data it seems to get `prep()` to work. Plus, I also need the fitted model/workflow to make predictions. So three objects it seems. If I save to disk the workflow object in SESSION 1 then I have the ability to extract the recipe and model from it in SESSION 2 with `pull_workflow_prepped_recipe()` and `pull_workflow_fit()` respectively. But `prep()` seems to require the original training data, which I can keep in the workflow with an earlier use of `retain = TRUE`...but then that gets stripped out of the workflow after a call to `fit()`. Hear my cries for help! :)

So, imagine two different R sessions, where the first session I am doing all the training and model building, and the second session is some running production app that uses what was learned from the first session. I need help at the arrows in the bottom of SESSION1, and in multiple places in SESSION 2. I used the Tidymodels [Get Started](https://www.tidymodels.org/start/recipes/) as the base for this example.

*SESSION 1*

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(nycflights13)
library(readr)
set.seed(123)
flight_data <- 
  head(flights, 500) %>% 
  mutate(
    arr_delay = ifelse(arr_delay >= 30, "late", "on_time"),
    arr_delay = factor(arr_delay),
    date = as.Date(time_hour)
  ) %>% 
  inner_join(weather, by = c("origin", "time_hour")) %>% 
  select(dep_time, flight, origin, dest, air_time, distance, carrier, date, arr_delay, time_hour) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)

set.seed(555)
data_split <- initial_split(flight_data, prop = 3/4)
train_data <- training(data_split)
test_data  <- testing(data_split)

flights_rec <- 
  recipe(arr_delay ~ ., data = train_data) %>% 
  update_role(flight, time_hour, new_role = "ID") %>% 
  step_date(date, features = c("dow", "month")) %>%
  step_holiday(date, holidays = timeDate::listHolidays("US")) %>%
  step_rm(date) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  step_zv(all_predictors())

lr_mod <- 
  logistic_reg() %>% 
  set_engine("glm")

flights_wflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_model(lr_mod) %>% 
  add_recipe(flights_rec)

flights_fit <- 
  flights_wflow %>% 
  fit(data = train_data)

predict(flights_fit, test_data)

### SAVE ONE OR MORE OBJECTS HERE FOR NEXT SESSION  <------------
# What to save? workflow (pre or post fit()?), recipe, training data...etc.
write_rds(flights_wflow, "flights_wflow.rds")  # Not fitted workflow
write_rds(flights_fit, "flights_fit.rds")  # Fitted workflow
```

*SESSION 2*

```r
### READ ONE OR MORE OBJECTS HERE FROM PRIOR SESSION <------------
flights_wflow <- read_rds("flights_wflow.rds")
flights_fit <- read_rds("flights_fit.rds")

# Acquire new data, do some basic transforms as before
new_flight_data <- 
  tail(flights, 500) %>% 
  mutate(
    arr_delay = ifelse(arr_delay >= 30, "late", "on_time"),
    arr_delay = factor(arr_delay),
    date = as.Date(time_hour)
  ) %>% 
  inner_join(weather, by = c("origin", "time_hour")) %>% 
  select(dep_time, flight, origin, dest, air_time, distance, carrier, date, arr_delay, time_hour) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)

# Something here to preprocess the data with recipe as in SESSION 1 <----------
# new_flight_data_prep <- prep(??)
# new_flight_data_preprocessed <- bake(??)

# Predict new data
predict(flights_fit, new_data = new_flight_data_preprocessed)
```

Answer (score 9):

You have some flexibility in how you approach this, depending on your constraints, but generally I would recommend saving/serializing the **fitted workflow**, perhaps after [using butcher to reduce its size](https://github.com/tidymodels/butcher). You can see [an example model fitting script in this repo](https://github.com/juliasilge/modelops-playground/blob/master/train-model/train.md) that shows at the end how I save the fitted workflow.

When you go to predict with this workflow, there are some things to keep in mind. I have [an example Plumber API](https://github.com/juliasilge/modelops-playground/blob/master/crash-api/plumber.R) in the same repo that demonstrates what is needed to predict for that particular workflow. Notice that the packages how the package needed for prediction are loaded/attached for this API. I didn't use all of tidymodels, but instead only the **specific packages** I need, for better performance and a smaller container.